# Is Option guaranteed to be atomic?

Tags: rust

If I have an `Option<T>` and I construct `T`, and then assign this, will the operation be atomic, as in will other threads get either `None` or `Some(T)` but definitely not part of `Some(T)`?

Comment: I feel like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what it means to be atomic.

Comment: What do you think it means, and what do think that I think atomic means (based on your feelings).

Comment: How would the other threads be accessing the option to begin with? It would help a lot of you provided more example code.

Comment: Singleton. For embedded systems. If you look at the cortex examples in the rust docs they have an example there. The system I am looking at is more constrained in memory (heap and stack) as weel as code size.

Comment: Are you using `unsafe` to assign to the singleton then? If you have specific code, you should also link it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Option is not designed with thread synchronization in mind.

However, you cannot observe interleaved reads because Rust's memory safety prevents you from modifying a value at all while its referenced in another thread. You would need a synchronization primitive like `Mutex` or `RwLock` to do that.

There is the [atomic-option](https://crates.io/crates/atomic-option) crate. Or perhaps just use an [`AtomicPtr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicPtr.html).

Comment: Was trying to avoid using a mutex. I don't have an std, but I think that the llvm intrisic atomic and/or memory barriers should do the trick.

Comment: These are all details that you should include in the question, otherwise you're asking people to guess details about your setup.